# Exception class with function params

Tags: php, exception, moodle, moodle-api

have been tasked with creating a separate file with an exception class function which is in turn called on another page when certain conditions are met. This implementation is purely for logging theses exceptions which will help with debugging.

I am struggling in creating this exception class and passing the params from the checking functions, not sure if this approach is the best.

in /local/user_enrolment/classes/mod_exception_errors.php I tried following the example from w3 schools

```
namespace mod_modulename;
function exceptions($exception, $userid) {
//userid references a param in another function and file
  echo "<b>Exception status is:</b> " . $exception->getMessage();
}
```

in another file where the user check happens I am thinking of doing something along these lines

```
public function checkuserexists($userid){
        global $DB;
        try {
            if ($DB->record_exists('user_course', ['id' => $userid])) {
            /*this is the error/where i am currently stuck, trying to call the function from
            local/user_enrolment/classes/mod_exception_errors.php
            
            $exception = mod_modulename::class){
            return the message and append level/status ie response should be
            $exception->getMessage();
            // Exception status is: 5 - user not found
            */
        }
        $user = $DB->get_record('user_course', array('id' => $userid));
        if (!empty($user)) {
        //check if user is active
            if ($user->status === 'active') {
            return $user->course_id;
            }
            $this->log_user_enrolled(sprintf(' local_new_enrolmentscheck_user: Mapping exists but not active'));
            }
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            $this-> local_new_enrolmentscheck_user($e->getMessage());
            return false;
            }
        }

protected function local_new_enrolmentscheck_user($errormessage) {
        error_log("Enrolment Error: $errormessage");
    }
```

I hope the question makes sense, this is just my thoughts of how I would approach but not really sure of the implemetation

TIA

Comment: Please format your code properly (and post the code "as is" in your code base, without rewrites.= It's hard to know what belongs to what in the second code block (it has some serious syntax issues atm). It would also help if you gave us some explanation of what currently happens when you run your code. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Hi @MagnusEriksson I have updated the question, the full function is still being worked on by another member, but its basically checking if a user exists in an course_user table which then checks for an active status. So my question is 2 part, how I would create the exception class using $userid param in the exception and calling it in the other class public function checkuserexists($userid){ ..